# Count groupby and melt dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
player  |   type
1            slow
2            fast
3            normal
2            fast
1            fast
3            normal
4            normal
4            normal
```

And I want to count each of the types and create a new column for each of these counts. It would look like this

```
player |   total_normal   | total_fast   | total_normal
1              0                1               1
2              0                2               0
3              2                0               0  
4              2                0               0
```

Any idea on how I can do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['player'], columns='type', aggfunc='size').fillna(0)
print(df)

type    fast  normal  slow
player                    
1        1.0     0.0   1.0
2        2.0     0.0   0.0
3        0.0     2.0   0.0
4        0.0     2.0   0.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Clean solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try pandas [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) :

```
pd.crosstab(df.player, df.type).add_prefix("total_")

type    total_fast  total_normal    total_slow
player          
   1       1            0              1
   2       2            0              0
   3       0            2              0
   4       0            2              0
```

`crosstab` and `pivot_table` can be quite slow. For more speed, I would suggest some manual control with `groupby`.